# Easiest way to get current unix timestamp via XSL

Tags: xslt

What is the easiest way to get current unix timestamp via XSL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT2, use the `current-dateTime()` function.

In XSLT1 you need the EXSLT extension function `date-time()`

However, be aware that different processors may behave differently if the function is evaluated more than once in a stylesheet.  The 'normal' behavior is for all calls in a given transformation to return the same value, so this cannot be used for profiling.

BTW, you could have done a simple [Google search on "xslt timestamp"](http://www.google.com/search?q=xslt+timestamp) to get this information.

Comment: Neither current-dateTime() nor date-time() really returns a unix timestamp. Is there another way to get it?

Comment: @user323094 Do you mean you want something to return milliseconds since the epoch?  You might need an external library to do that, or convert from the time value.