# get current unix timestamp in XSLT

Tags: xslt, datetime, timestamp, xslt-1.0

How do I get current unix timestamp in XSLT?

I need XSLT 1.0 solution, but feel free to mention XSLT 2.0 solutions if you know them.

I need the unix timestamp, not just any format of date and time - this question has been asked before in [Easiest way to get current unix timestamp via XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867114/easiest-way-to-get-current-unix-timestamp-via-xsl) but the accepted answer is not a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Plain XSLT/XPath 1.0 doesn't provide any date/time functions, but if [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/) is an option, you can use its [date module](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html). I haven't tested it, but it should be possible to get the current Unix timestamp this way:

```
date:seconds(date:difference('1970-01-01T00:00:00', date:date-time()))
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought of solving it this way, but unfortunately, date:difference() is not among core EXSLT functions and my XSLT processor happens not to support it.

Comment: In this case you can possibly use the [implementation of `date:difference`](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/date.difference.zip) available from the EXSLT website. As far as I see, it requires the support of the functions module only.